# networkx multiple LCA in DAG

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to use the networkx package in python to find the lowest common ancestor for 2 nodes in a graph. When I use the built in method for this it only retrieves one LCA when there are multiple. Any ideas of how to retrieve all LCAs?

Example:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(1,2)
nx.all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor(G, 2,3) # returns 1
G.add_edge(4,3)
G.add_edge(4,2)
nx.all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor(G, 2,3) # returns 4 # desired return should be 1 and 4
```

Answer (score 0):

What is probably confusing you is that `nx.all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor` returns a *single* lowest common ancestor (only one, even if there are several on the same level). What is meant by `all_pairs...` is that it finds the common ancestor for all pairs of specified nodes. That means that, considering for instance the following graph, we could do:

[image]

```
list(nx.all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor(G, [('pine','eucaliptus'), ('pine','daisy')]))
# [(('pine', 'daisy'), 'plant'), (('pine', 'eucaliptus'), 'tree')]
```

And get the lowest common ancestor for all the specified pairs. But in your example, since you've only specified one pair, you get its corresponding LCA:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(4,3)
G.add_edge(4,2)
```

[image]

```
list(nx.all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor(G, pairs=[(2, 3)]))
# [((2, 3), 4)]
```

Which is the same as:

```
nx.lowest_common_ancestor(G, 2,3)
# 4
```

Comment: Any idea of how to find all LCAs for two nodes? For example, in a graph of two siblings sharing two parents, I would want both parent nodes listed as LCAs, not just the first parent.